# Popup with StaysOpen to false is not closing

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I have a telerik grid view and when I right click the header, I'm showing a  with a ListBox inside containing the list of columns.

The item template is redefined to show a check box so I can set the column visible or not.
I can also drag/drop columns to reorder them.

So here is how I create my Popup:

```
var view = new ColumnsOrderer.ColumnsOrderer
            {
                DataContext = new ColumnsOrderer.ViewModelColumnsOrderer(Columns)
            };

var codePopup = new Popup
                    {
                        Child = view,
                        MaxHeight = 400,
                        StaysOpen = false,
                        Placement = PlacementMode.Mouse
                    };
codePopup.IsOpen = true;
```

Now everything seems to work correctly, but it's not.
If I set columns visible or hidden and then click outside the popup, it closes correctly.

Though if I drag an item to reorder it, the popup seems to lose focus and then it won't close if I click outside the popup. I have to click back in the list box inside the popup and then it closes by clicking outside.

Here is my drag/drop events:

```
public ColumnsOrderer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitialiazeListBoxDragDrop();
}

private void InitialiazeListBoxDragDrop()
{
    var itemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));

    itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(AllowDropProperty, true));
    itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseMoveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseMove)));
    itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DropEvent, new DragEventHandler(OnDrop)));

    listColumns.ItemContainerStyle = itemContainerStyle;
}

void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is CheckBox || e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
        return;

    if (sender is ListBoxItem)
    {
        var draggedItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
        draggedItem.IsSelected = true;

        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, draggedItem.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}

void OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is ListBoxItem))
        return;
}
```

An interesting thing is that if I remove the OnDrop handler, the problem is not there.
I tried many ways to set back the focus to the popup, but it's not working.

Could anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to re-focus your `Popup` control after the drag and drop operation?

```
void OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is ListBoxItem))
        return;
    codePopup.Focus();
}
```

Comment: OnDrop is in codeBehind of a control inside the popup. I don't want get the parent casted as Popup to set its focus. This control could be use elsewhere...

Comment: Even if I don't want to do it, I tried it and it's not working